# Resolving header dependencies in setup.py

Tags: python, windows, pcap, winpcap, packet-construction-set

I'm having difficulty installing a Python module on Windows.  There are dependencies with the libpcap and winpcap libraries.

When trying to run 'setup.py' I receive fatal errors and the script aborts like the one below

```
Cannot open include file: 'pcap.h': No such file or directory
```

I downloaded the source files and included them in my PATH Environmental Variable but they don't seem to be resolved. I am able to systematically locate and move files into the expected directory structure like the 'pcap.h' from the error above.  However it would be much easier to have the script reference the correct libraries so I don't have to hack it for my box.

I assume I need to the modify portion of the code below in setup.py

```
bpf = Extension(name='bpf',
        sources=[ 'pcs/bpf/bpf.pyx' ],
        include_dirs=['/usr/include/pcap'],
        library_dirs=['/usr/lib'],
        libraries=['pcap']
    )
```

I have tried running install using both cygwin and minigw

Comment: you missed a closing single quote on include_dirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/issues/detail?id=11)?

```
winpcap development is free. http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpdPack_4_0_2.zip

1) Download MinGW32. Install to c:\wingw32
2) path=%path%;c:\wingw32\bin
3) Download winpcap development pack from above. Unzip to c:\WpdPack
4) From pypcap-1.1 directory. 
   > python .\setup.py --with-pcap="C:\WpdPack"
   > python .\setup.py build -cmingw32
   > python .\setup.py install
```